# how to apply authentication middleware with direct function calling using firebase cloud function on backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, middleware

I'm using direct function calling with firebase cloud functions and want to authenticate every functions with token for backend server

- not using HTTP endpoints like firebase provide sample functions [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/authenticated-json-api/functions/index.js)
- calling all functions like below

`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Method not allowed'
        })
    }
    var db = admin.firestore();
    return db.doc('channels/' + req.query.id).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            return res.send(snapshot.data())
        })
        .catch(reason => {
            return res.send(reason)
        })
});
```

Please tell me how can i use auth middleware with these type of functions and correct me if going in wrong direction

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting no response, i decide to go with HTTP request for function calling, with that authentications are pretty state forward, but still warm welcome good solution for my question.